# Any php script to sign transaction?

Tags: ether

Can you recommend some php script to sign transaction.Thanks.I want to find some php script to sign transaction and without using web3.

Comment: This question may be helpful to you https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/62774/invalid-sender-when-sending-raw-transaction-signed-w-ethereum-tx-on-php

Answer (score 0):

Use the following library.

https://github.com/kornrunner/php-ethereum-offline-raw-tx

Use the library to create and sign the transaction with ease.

Comment: How do you sign the transaction with the php-ethereum-offline-raw-tx package?

Comment: It seems there is auto signing https://github.com/kornrunner/php-ethereum-offline-raw-tx/blob/029f8b94be48cf051ad56dd405a0bcd24209e7bb/src/Ethereum/Transaction.php#L67